# Inversion: "Not only, but also"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have doubts with the inversion of **Not only, but also** (in cases, where we want to emphasize something)

Is it correct to use it in the sentence like this below?

> Our final goal will be **not only** students do acquire the communicative
>   competence, they should **also** learn different things related to the
>   society.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the first part of this sentence without the **not only**,

> Our final goal will be students do acquire the communicative competence

There is something missing from this sentence: you need to use a conjunction [that](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that) to link the two clauses. You have used **should** in the second part, and I recommend that you use it instead of **do** in the first part as well. You don't need a definite article before **communicative competence**, because [competence](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/competence) is normally a non-count noun.

> Our final goal will be **that** students **should** acquire communicative competence

Adding the second part:

> Our final goal will be that students should **not only** acquire communicative competence, **but also** learn different things related to society.

Note that **not only** and **but also** act as coordinating conjunctions for a [parallel structure](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/1/): They section following them must be the same for both parts. In this case, they appear before the verb in both parts, and **students should** applies to both of them.

I would also recommend rewording it a little to make it more natural:

> Our final goal **is** that students should not only acquire **communication skills**, but also learn different things **about** society.

You might also consider replace **different things** by **more**.